# jQuery UI Autocomplete - Custom style when we have jQuery UI Theme style sheet referenced

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using [jQuery UI Autocomplate plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) as it is on the first example. I also have jQuery UI Theme style sheet referenced for other plugins.

This is the input I am using with that:

CSS:

```
div.formvalue {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
}

div.paddedInput {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}

div.paddedInput input {
    border: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    outline:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="formvalue">
    <div class="paddedInput"><input type="text" value="Padded!" /></div>
</div>
```

Here is my situation:

As the above div element serves as an input element (on the style perspective), the autocomplete list looks a little awkward because it sets itself for the input element.

I dug the source code which jQuery UI is creating for the autocomplete function and there is `ui-autocomplete` style class but as I said but I couldn't figure auto what should I override.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the jsfiddle sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/tugberk/YxRYe/4/

Comment: So you're trying to edit the UI style of the drop down for an auto-complete widget? Where are you actually making the UI widget?

Comment: @SuperTron yes. I am not sure what you mean by where?

Comment: Well, what class are you applying the "autocomplete" to? Something like: `$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({source: availableTags});` Are you doing that on the "paddedInput" class?

Comment: @SuperTron no, I am just testing it for now and this is the only input element inside the DOM. So, I use element selector: `$("input[type=text]" ).autocomplete({source: availableTags});`

Comment: @SuperTron see this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/tugberk/YxRYe/4/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overwrite your style, you can use `!important` keyword as this code

```
div.paddedInput input {
    border: 0px!important;
    width: 100%;
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: you didn't get me. Here is a sample of mine. http://jsfiddle.net/tugberk/YxRYe/4/

Answer (score 0):

I guess the main question here is why you would  have the outer div element serve as an input element from a style perspective in the first place.

If this is not a requirement, just do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hrrw8/). Otherwise we'll have to use JS to set the width of the dropdown to the width of the div and adjust the position of the dropdown. A rather hacky solution i.m.o. I am not aware of a way to specify what element the dropdown should attach to since this is rarely what you want.